# oracle select query based on other table row level condition

Tags: oracle

I want to find the orders number from table#orders where DelivaryDateRevision less than max revisions from each country(table#maxrevisions). Countrycode is not the foreign key to the other table.

Can I fetch the orders table records if the country code is missing in the maxrevisions table.

Table: orders

```
OrderNumber | CountryCode | DelivaryDateRevision
123--------------- IN-------------------9  
234--------------- US-------------------3
238--------------  IN------------------ 3
```

table: maxrevisions

```
CountryCode|  MaxRevision
IN ---------------6
US--------------- 4
```

My query:

```
SELECT distinct o.ordernumber,o.countrycode
FROM orders o
     left outer join maxrevisions m
       on o.CountryCode=m.CountryCode
       and
       o.DelivaryDateRevision<rs.MaxRevision;
```

but I am getting the wrong result. Can I get any help here?

Comment: Please show us order data which does not have a matching max revision.  And, in that case, what does the output look like?

Comment: if we add order row  444--------------  DE------------------ 10 .. in the output i need to get orders 234, 238 and 444. i have used left outer join. but still i am missing some thing. please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your major omission seems to be a `WHERE` clause which compares the two revisions:

```
SELECT
    o.ordernumber,
    o.countrycode
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN maxrevisions m
    ON o.CountryCode = m.CountryCode
WHERE
    o.DelivaryDateRevision < m.MaxRevision OR m.MaxRevision IS NULL;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I need one more help here. if maxrevisions table doesn't have countrycode and that time i need to pick the orders or other country codes. now country code is not foreign key. And all requirement is same. can anyone help here.

Comment: @user1135690 You should not change your question after others have already answered.  That being said, you may update your question and give us logic for what should happen if a max revision is missing for a given country code.

Comment: My apologies and thanks for the response. can i update my question now.

Comment: @user1135690 I have updated my answer per your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  ordernumber,
  countrycode,
  deliverydateversion 
from orders o 
where deliverydateversion > 
(
  select max(revision) 
  from maxrevisiontab 
  where countrycode= o.countrycode
)
```

Please change the table names and column names as per your structure.